# JSOUP. How to extract data with select on this page?

Tags: java, jsoup

Hello I'm new using "jsoup"
And tried to extract data from this page but for more that I combine the "id" and "class" does not show me anything.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Fp4.png)

The code is this:

```
 Document d = getHtmlDocument("http://www.mismarcadores.com/futbol/inglaterra/league-one/resultados/"); 
 System.out.println("El Status Code  es: "+getStatusConnectionCode("http://www.mismarcadores.com/futbol/inglaterra/league-one/resultados/"));

Elements ele=d.select("#fs-results");
System.out.println("Numero de entradas en la pagina mismarcadores: "+ele.size()+"\n");
```

With other pages if it extract your information.

Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll be after something like this:

```
Element element = d.getElementById("fs-results");
```

or

```
Elements elements = d.getElementsByClass("fs-table");
```

Comment: In the page source the tag you point to is empty.  <div id="fs-results" class="fs-table tournament-page"></div>

Answer (score 0):

The tag that contains data for this page is <div id="tournament-page-data-results">.  This code will get you that data.  However, the format of the data is very strange to me and I am not able to help with that.
Sometimes to find the data, right-click on the page in a browser, "view source code", look through the source code and identify the tag with the data.

```
Document d = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
//Option 1.
Element element = d.getElementById("tournament-page-data-results");
System.out.println(element.text());
//Option 2 with select.
Elements element2 = d.select("#tournament-page-data-results");
System.out.println(element2.get(0).text());
```